# How to hide a WooCommerce product once a user logs in?

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I have had no luck Googling or asking the above question of various plugin boards, so it's back to old faithful.

I have the 'groups' plugin installed and it's working very well so far, but how can I hide a subscription product once a user has logged on, i.e. a user has already purchased that product? Is there a way to allocate a group to a non-logged in user?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply add 'is_user_logged_in()' to your custom products-archive.php loop. Nothing to do with the groups plugin.